# application which allows creating virtual serial port with parity support

Tags: windows, serial-port, port, virtual, parity

I am trying to create 2 virtual serial ports in my windows7-64 bit machine to run my applications which communicate over serial ports.

I have tried these software:- 
FreeVirtualSerialPort, KerProAdvancedVirtualComPort, VirtualSerialPortDriver, VirtualSerialPortEmulator, VirtualSerialPortKit and com0com

The communication works fine, however I am unable to receive parity bit with the data. Just want to know if someone has used any of these or other software and received parity correctly. My applications use Mark and Space parity. Is there a software which supports 9-bit communication.

Comment: Usually it is 7 bits with parity and 8 bits without.

Comment: my understanding is, it is 8 bit without parity and 9 bit with parity.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Hasn't been that way for 30 years

Answer (score 0):

The parity errors are detected by hardware and reported to driver. It is then upto driver and serial port configurations about how to handle this error. If the application has requested to get notified about parity error operating system specific action is taken for example setting a particular flag which app can use to determine whether error happened or not.

Very few application uses 9th bit and also hardware supporting them are also less. There is an [article also about 9th bit](https://github.com/RishiGupta12/SerialPundit/blob/master/applications/9-bit-data.md). BTW why you need 9th bit at app level.

Comment: thank you @Hercules dd for helping. my application is communicating using an old serial protocol. and the first byte of the message is determined by the parity bit. this means, for a 4 byte message, parity bit will be set to 1 for first byte, and parity bit will be set to 0 for remaining 3 bytes.